# Select dataframe row from rowname using case-insensitive (like `grep -i`)

Tags: python, pandas, select, case-insensitive

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
In [1]: mydict = {"1421293_at Hdgfl1":[2.140412,1.143337,3.260313],
                  "1429877_at Lrriq3":[9.019368,0.874524,2.051820]}

In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]:  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                          0         1         2
1421293_at Hdgfl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
1429877_at Lrriq3  9.019368  0.874524  2.051820
```

What I want to do is to select the the row from the row name, using a case-insensitive query.
For example given the query "hdgfl1" it should return:

```
                                         0                1               2
1421293_at Hdgfl1                 2.140412          1.143337          3.260313
```

"hdgfl1" is the case-insensitive query of "1421293_at Hdgfl1". Basically equivalent to `grep -i`.

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [229]: df.filter(regex=r'(?i)hdgfl1', axis=0)
Out[229]: 
                          0         1         2
1421293_at Hdgfl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
query = 'hdgfl1'
mask = df.index.to_series().str.contains(query, case=False)
df[mask]
```

Another possibility would be:

```
mask = df.reset_index()['index'].str.contains(query, case=False)
```

but this is 2x slower.

Comment: This is what `df.filter()` is for... admittedly the best-hidden pandas command I know of

Answer (score -1):

And with select():

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

mydict = {
"1421293_at Hdgfl1":[2.140412,1.143337,3.260313],
"1429877_at Lrriq3":[ 9.019368,0.874524,2.051820],
"1421293_at hDGFl1":[2.140412,1.143337,3.260313],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')

def create_match_func(a_str):
    def match_func(x):
        pattern = r".* {}".format(a_str)
        match_obj = re.search(pattern, x, flags=re.X|re.I)
        return match_obj

    return match_func

print df
print '-' * 20

target = "hdgfl1"
print df.select(create_match_func(target), axis=0)

--output:--
                          0         1         2
1421293_at Hdgfl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
1429877_at Lrriq3  9.019368  0.874524  2.051820
1421293_at hDGFl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
--------------------
                          0         1         2
1421293_at Hdgfl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
1421293_at hDGFl1  2.140412  1.143337  3.260313
```

...

```
df.select(lambda x: x == 'A', axis=1)
```

`select()` takes a `function` which operates on the label(s) along `axis` and the
function should return `a boolean`.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-select-method

Comment: This is unnecessary, reinventing the wheel which `df.filter()` already provides. Also, `df.select()` has been deprecated in favor of `df.loc()` since pandas 0.21